# How can I dismiss a HERE Maps context menu programmatically?

Tags: javascript, contextmenu, here-api, heremaps

I have a HERE Maps map displayed on a simple webpage with a multiselect dropdown and a couple of buttons. I'm using the `contextmenu` event to show a context menu on right-click, like so:

```
var map = new H.Map(
    document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
    maptypes.raster.normal.map,
    {
        zoom: 12,
        center: { lat: -33.81, lng: 150.78 },
        pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1,
        engineType: H.map.render.RenderEngine.EngineType.P2D
    }
);

...

// an H.map.Polygon object we prepared earlier
polygonObject.addEventListener("contextmenu", handleContextMenu)

...

function handleContextMenu(evt) {
    // Don't do anything if the map itself is right-clicked/long-pressed
    if (evt.target === map) {
        return;
    }

    if (evt.target instanceof H.map.Polygon) {
        // Polygon-specific context menu items
        evt.items.push(new H.util.ContextItem({ label: "ABC123" }));
        evt.items.push(H.util.ContextItem.SEPARATOR);
        evt.items.push(new H.util.ContextItem({ label: "Do something", callback: function () { doSomething(evt) } }));
    }
}
```

This works fine, displays a context menu when a polygon object is right-clicked, and dismisses itself if somewhere else on the map is tapped. However, the context menu doesn't dismiss if the user clicks or interacts with another element on the page *outside* the map.

I wasn't able to find any documentation on how to achieve this behaviour, and the [example that HERE Maps uses](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/events/context-menu) also doesn't dismiss the context menu if somewhere outside the map is clicked. Is there any way to dismiss the context menu on a map, either programmatically or automatically if another page element is interacted with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little bit hacky, but you can manually remove the context menu from the DOM by finding a `div` with the `h_context_menu` class in the page, and removing it. This may have some unintended side effects with the UI class, but seems to work OK from my brief testing.

Using JQuery:

```js
$("div.h_context_menu").remove()
```

Using ES6:

```
document.querySelector("div.h_context_menu").remove()
```

Using vanilla JavaScript (compatible with Internet Explorer):

```
var el = document.querySelector("div.h_context_menu");
el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
```